# How can I call a specific page everytime than a event occurs?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this follow code in my javascript.

I call this function when the user click in a specific checkbox and then I just change the image of this checkbox.

the problem is that my ExportaZap are accessed just one time, for example, if a click now in my checkbox, I call ExportaZap.ashx and then change the image of this checkbox. If a click again, he don't pass through my ExportaZap.ashx.

How can I do to call ExportaZap ever than my user click on my checkbox using the function below ?

```
    function Visibilidade(id, imagemBaixa, credenciada) {
            $.get("../Action/ExportaZap.ashx", { id: id, imagemBaixa: imagemBaixa, credenciada: credenciada }, function (data) {
                if (data != "limite") {

                    if ($("#" + imagemBaixa).attr("src") == "../tema/default/images/CheckVerde.png") {
                        $("#" + imagemBaixa).attr("src", "../tema/default/images/CheckCinza.jpg");
                    }
                    else if ($("#" + imagemBaixa).attr("src") == "../tema/default/images/CheckCinza.jpg") {
                        $("#" + imagemBaixa).attr("src", "../tema/default/images/CheckVerde.png");
});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
        Visibilidade(this.id, imagemBaixa, credenciada);
    });
}
```

Comment: I put a new parameter, calling the Math.random(2), I think it was cache.